# UITextField: Leading Truncate

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

Currently, my text within a UITextField is truncating at the tail (eg. "Hello, Wor..."). I want the to truncate the text from the leading edge (eg. "...lo, World!").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using `NSMutableParagraphStyle's lineBreakMode` with `NSMutableAttributedString` might work

```
let longString = "Hello World"

// Just for demo purposes, you can use auto layout etc
let textfield = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 200, width: 30, height: 100))
textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2
textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

// Use a paragraph style to define the truncation method
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead

// Create an attributed string and apply the paragraph style
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: longString)
attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                              value: paragraphStyle,
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// Set the text field's attributed text as the attributed string
textfield.attributedText = attributedString
```

This gives something like this, which is what I think you want:

[image: UITextField Leading Truncation iOS Swift]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to update the text attributes (e.g., [`defaultTextAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619618-defaulttextattributes)) with a [`.paragraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1527910-paragraphstyle) with a [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1535126-linebreakmode) of [`.byTruncatingHead`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode/bytruncatinghead).

I would not just replace the `.paragraphStyle`, though. I would fetch it, update its `lineBreakMode`, and then update the text attributes with that:

```swift
let oldStyle = textField.defaultTextAttributes[.paragraphStyle, default: NSParagraphStyle()] as! NSParagraphStyle
let style = oldStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
style.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
textField.defaultTextAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = style
```

---

Here it is with `.byTruncatingHead`, `.byTruncatingMiddle` and `.byTruncatingTail`, respectively:

[image]